# Only one line of this batch file will run

Tags: python, batch-file, gdal

```
gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_merged.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_nn20.tif 
gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_nn20.tif
gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r026_7t20001010_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r026_7t20001010_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r026_7t20001010_z16_nn20.tif 
gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r026\p024r026_7t20000729_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r026\p024r026_7t20000729_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r026\p024r026_7t20000729_z16_nn20.tif 
gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r028\p023r028_7t20000519_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r028\p023r028_7t20000519_z16_nn10.tif 

C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p023r026\p023r028\p023r028_7t20000519_z16_nn20.tif
```

Note: I've removed the other 5 file names from each command to make it a bit more readable. 
I'm working on a Python tool that will construct a batch file for me but when I attempt to run this .bat all I get is the first command running successfully then returning to console. I'm running it in the FWTools shell. I've opened the batch file in a hex editor and searched for extra newlines and return characters but I don't see anything out of the ordinary so Python seems to be writing correctly.

Comment: Although not strictly a GIS issue, you might have some luck asking your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com. Here's fine, too, though, since it's (possibly) more of a python issue rather than something to do with the GIS tool you're using.

Comment: Could you try to present an example that we can use to reproduce the error? Like described [here](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 4):

is `gdal_merge` a batch file itself?

In that case you need to enter `call` before each line to prompt the batch file to return on exit from the called batch file, otherwise the exit call in the new batch file will be treated as a real exit so shall exit completely:

```
call gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_merged.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p023r027\p023r027_7t20010623_z16_nn20.tif 
call gdal_merge -o C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_merged.tif -seperate -q -v C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_nn10.tif C:\test\RasterMerge\p024r027\p024r027_7t19990828_z16_nn20.tif
...
```

(it is also possible that python itself is run though a batch file, than the same applies, but possibly you can also use `call python gdal_merge.py -o ...`)

If this is not a batch file then try using `start /B` instead of `call` as this will fork a new background task. If you need these to be called sequentially rather than in parallel then just use `start /B /WAIT`.